# Alert Message on event

Tags: javascript, alert

I am looking for a way to change the following javascript so that when a user clicks on right button, it shows a custom message in alert box.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function mousedwn(e) { 
try { if (event.button == 2||event.button == 3) return false; }  
catch (e) { if (e.which == 3) return false; }

}
    document.oncontextmenu = function() { return false; }
    document.ondragstart   = function() { return false; }
    document.onmousedown   = mousedwn;
    </script>
```

Comment: With right button you mean the right mouse click? try this:`<div oncontextmenu="javascript:alert('your msg');return false;"> Lorem Ipsum </div>`

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code for disabling right click with alert/without alert.

```
<script language=JavaScript>
<!--

//edit by unwanted


var message="PUT YOUR MESSEGE HERE";

///////////////////////////////////
function clickIE4(){
if (event.button==2){
alert(message);
return false;
}
}

function clickNS4(e){
if (document.layers||document.getElementById&&!document.all){
if (e.which==2||e.which==3){
alert(message);
return false;
}
}
}

if (document.layers){
document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);
document.onmousedown=clickNS4;
}
else if (document.all&&!document.getElementById){
document.onmousedown=clickIE4;
}

document.oncontextmenu=new Function("alert(message);return false")

// -->
</script>
```

Thanks,

Siva